# Reestricción de borrado en tabla de mysql

Tags: mysql

Alguien puede indicarme si es posible bloquear una tabla para borrado cuando uno de sus campos no sea Nulo.

Requiero hacerlo desde el manejador de base de datos, no con codigo.

Comment: No se si entiendo muy bien tu pregunta. Quieres poder hacer delete cuando algún campo sea nulo? Impedir que el delete se haga? Podrias explicarte un poco mejor?

Answer (score 3):

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER mi_trigger
BEFORE DELETE
ON Mi_tabla
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF OLD.CAMPO_A_VALIDAR IS NOT NULL THEN -- Parar borrado si este campo NO es null
    CALL cannot_delete_error; -- Error a lanzar para impedir el borrado
  END IF;
END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

1. Se crea el trigger contra el evento DELETE
2. Se comprueba el campo CAMPO_A_VALIDAR en el objeto OLD (registro en BD).
3. Si es NULL se
   lanza el error cannot_delete_error para impedir la operación.

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias. Abusando de tu amabilidad, debo crear el procedimiento cannot_delete_error?

Comment: No soy demasiado experto en MySQL precisamente, pero creo que es un error predefinido, así que no sería necesario.